# Can't await work on a computation other than functions in python3.5?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, python-3.5

Does it have to be a function we are not blocking ?
Why isn't this working?

```
async def trivial(L):
    await [num**2 for num in L]
```

So "Object list can't be used in 'await' expression", Am I correct in assuming it's only looking for a function or is there something that's possible to await??

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#await-expression), `await` will:

> Suspend the execution of `coroutine` on an `awaitable` object.

You're in a coroutine, but a list is not [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-awaitable), it isn't *"a `coroutine` or an object with an `__await__()` method."*

Note that the list comprehension is fully evaluated, resulting in a list, before it gets passed to `await`, so there's no work left to be done at that point anyway. If you were doing something more complex than `num**2` inside the loop, you could consider rewriting the process as an [*"asynchronous iterator"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for) and using `async for`, as follows:

```
async def trivial(L):
    result = []
    async for item in process(L):
        result.apend(item)
```

This would allow other pending tasks to be run between iterations of your process over `L`.